# I can see the seam of meshes in rendered image

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm trying to render light bulbs, but I'm facing a problem in subdivision-surface modifier.

I applied Subsurf modifier for each glass of bulb with UV sphere and Solidify modifier after it.

I chose 4 for Subsurf modifier for each glass of bulbs but it showed the seam of mesh of bulbs like below.

[image]

So I've tried giving more divisions(6) and ended up with Out of memory error of CUDA.

I tried it with only one bulb and it looks much better.

[image]

Is this normal behavior? or Did I do something wrong?

Giving more subdivisions for all the bulbs are not feasible with GPU rendering.

Please share any techniques, if you know, to make the bulbs more smooth.

Comment: can you share the blend file?

Comment: Why not just use smooth shading?

Comment: pycoder has it right, you have flat shading enabled, open your tools panel on the left (hit t) and click 'Smooth', subsurf level 2, or 3 should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, @pycoder. Smooth just works for me :D. This looks very fundamental BTW. Sorry for the question like this.

Comment: You might also want to reconsider your topology from uv sphere style poles, to a polysphere (basically a subdivided cube shrinkwrapped around a sphere) to avoid pinching at the poles.